# How can I return dynamic string array in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, dapps, string

How can I return a dynamic string array? I came across serialization and deserialization. How can I serialize and deserialize dynamic string array ?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Abc{
    string[] st;

    function add(string memory newValue) public {
        st.push(newValue);
    }

    // return st
```

Answer (score 6):

As of Solidity `0.7.5` the `ABIEncoderV2` is not experimental anymore and can be selected using the pragma directive.

This gives native support for returning dynamic string arrays from functions.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;
pragma abicoder v2;

contract Abc {
    string[] st;

    function add(string memory newValue) public {
        st.push(newValue);
    }

    function getSt() public view returns (string[] memory) {
        return st;
    }
}
```

On a side note, starting with Solidity `0.8.0` `abicoder v2` is enabled by default and the pragma directive can therefore be omitted.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is not support from solidity for returning an array of strings as described here:

[Return dynamic array of string](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/frequently-asked-questions.html#is-it-possible-to-return-an-array-of-strings-string-from-a-solidity-function)

You can fix it adopting this workaround described here:

[Deserialize a string](https://hackernoon.com/serializing-string-arrays-in-solidity-db4b6037e520)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ABIEncoderV2`:

```solidity
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Foo {
  string [] private strings;

  function addString (string memory str) public {
    strings.push (str);
  }

  function getStrings () public view returns (string [] memory) {
    return strings;
  }
}
```

See [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.7/layout-of-source-files.html?highlight=ABIEncoderV2#abiencoderv2) for details.